# How can I remove keys with values of 0, while scanning the dictionary to search for keys with values of 0?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `dictionary` of **names and numbers**; where `names are keys` and `numbers are the values` in the `dictionary`. I am **decrementing the numbers** of each key, where at some point the numbers will hit 0.

When they hit 0, I would like to remove the corresponding key from the dictionary. In my code, when I try to do this- I get an error, because as I **loop through the dictionary** searching for keys with **0 as values**, and `pop()` them from the `dictionary`- I get an error that says the size of dictionary changes during the iteration.

How can I achieve the above without the error? Am I wrong in looping over the dictionary to remove keys with values of 0? - I understand the problem and agree that it is an issue, but can't seem to think of a way to achieve this!

Would I need to initialise an array/set to store the keys with values of 0, then remove them after?- or is there a more efficient way?

```
pat = dict()

pat['ff']= 5
pat['dd'] = 4
pat['pat'] = 0

for i in pat:
    if pat[i] == 0:
        pat.pop(i)

Error: RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: Please provide your code and the exception you encounter.

Comment: hmmmm, why not loop twice sequentially ? in the first loop the append the keys to remove to a list. and in the second loop pop them

Comment: I believe I understand it now; it is because I was iterating over the dictionary while popping that caused the error. I believe Srikanth's way as I described above; to create another list of keys to pop is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code gives the output as expected

```
my_dict = {'a': 4, 'b':3, 'c':2, 'd':0}
del_keys= []
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if value == 0:
        del_keys.append(key)
for key in del_keys:
    my_dict.pop(key)
print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `list(d.keys())` while iterating

```
d = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
for i in list(d.keys()): #Use like this
    d[i] -= 1
    if d[i] ==0:
        del d[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities, but would like to point python's [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Removing zeroed elements is as simple as

```
my_counter += Counter()
```

And you can substract from values with [subtract](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.subtract)

Comment: Thanks kosciej, but is there a way to remove keys? I am familiar with counter to keep a count of occurrences of keys.

Comment: Yes, the line I posted removes keys with count less or equal than zero. And in case you can use del too to remove other.